# SharePoint Custom Action on Site Settings Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, custom-action

I have a Custom Action on the Site Settings page of my SharePoint site that appears in the UsersAndPermissions list. It is created using a feature, this is the elements.xml file for the feature:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="SDITeamGroupApplicationPage"
    GroupId="UsersAndPermissions"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
    Sequence="1000"
    Title="Create a Team Group">
    <UrlAction Url="_layouts/SDITeamGroupEdit.aspx"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Currently all the users of site can see this link on the Site Settings page. I want to be able to restrict who can see this link. Is this possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx

Look for the elements called "Rights" and or "RequireSiteAdminstrator" etc.

Here are the list of possible "Rights":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a visual studio solution which uses CustomAction for such requirements.

Here is the step by step instructions to build a visual studio solution which adds new custom link in site settings page: [Add a Link to Site Settings Page in SharePoint.](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/add-link-to-site-settings-page-in-sharepoint-2010.html#ixzz2anmlCgRw)